# Multilayer perceptron always picks the last class it was trained to specify. Backpropagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, perceptron

I'm trying to write a MLP that classifies input into three objects.
I have a number that represents each object.

```
1-10 : Banana
11-20 : Apple
21:30 : Carrot
```

There's only two layers in MLP: one hidden layer (2 units) and one output layer (3 units).
Each unit has:

- inputs[] (inputs that were passed to this unit)
- weights[]
- delta
- sum (summed up weights with inputs)
- output (activated sum)

also each unit has an activation function:

```
double activate(double[] inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
            sum += weights[i] * inputs[i];

        output = 1.0 / (1.0 + (Math.exp(-sum))); // activation

        return output;
    }
```

and a function to correct weights:

```
void correctWeights(double momentum, double learningRate) {
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
            weights[i] = weights[i] * momentum + learningRate * delta * (output * (1 - output)) * inputs[i];
        }
    }
```

where `(output * (1 - output))` is the derivative.

To train the network I have a function that loops N times, in the loop I generate the input relative to the object, then propagate it to the network and use back-propagation.

```
private void train() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            int[] expectedOutput = new int[3];
            double[] inputs = {ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 30 + 1)};
            if (inputs[0] <= 10) {
                expectedOutput[0] = 1;
                expectedOutput[1] = 0;
                expectedOutput[2] = 0;
            }
            if (inputs[0] <= 20 && inputs[0] > 10) {
                expectedOutput[0] = 0;
                expectedOutput[1] = 1;
                expectedOutput[2] = 0;
            }
            if (inputs[0] <= 30 && inputs[0] > 20) {
                expectedOutput[0] = 0;
                expectedOutput[1] = 0;
                expectedOutput[2] = 1;
            }
            double[] outputs = propagate(inputs);
            backPropagate(expectedOutput, outputs);
        }
    }
```

Propagation function just goes through the whole net and activates the units.

```
private double[] propagate(double[] inputs) {
        double[] hiddenOutputs = new double[hiddenLayer.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayer.length; i++)
            hiddenOutputs[i] = hiddenLayer[i].activate(inputs);

        double[] outputs = new double[outputLayer.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++)
            outputs[i] = outputLayer[i].activate(hiddenOutputs);

        return outputs;
    }
```

Back-propagation algorithm was taken from http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html

```
private void backPropagate(int[] expectedOutput, double[] output) {
        for (int i = 0; i < outputLayer.length; i++) {
            outputLayer[i].setDelta(expectedOutput[i] - output[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayer.length; i++) {
            double delta = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < outputLayer.length; j++) {
                delta += outputLayer[j].getDelta() * outputLayer[j].getWeight(i);
            }
            hiddenLayer[i].setDelta(delta);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayer.length; i++)
            hiddenLayer[i].correctWeights(momentum, learningRate);

        for (int i = 0; i < outputLayer.length; i++)
            outputLayer[i].correctWeights(momentum, learningRate);
    }
```

It also has a function to recognize objects after it got trained

```
private void recognize(String number) {
        double[] inputs = {Double.parseDouble(number)};
        double[] outputs = propagate(inputs);
        System.out.println("Banana: " + outputs[0]);
        System.out.println("Apple: " + outputs[1]);
        System.out.println("Carrot: " + outputs[2]);
    }
```

So the problem is that when I pass any number to the **recognize** function I get the output similar to this:

```
Banana: 0.49984367018594233
Apple: 0.49984367018594233
Carrot: 0.5001563298140577
```

Carrot is being chosen every time (also carrot is the last trained object by the net). So if I input 5 it will output that it's a carrot. if I input 15 it will output that it's a carrot. If I change the order of the objects that are being learned in **train** function and make the banana to be the last learned object then the net will always pick the banana as its answer.

I've been working on this for a few days now and I couldn't find any solution to it, please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is very important to shuffle your data, i.e. randomly pick a number between 1 and 30 as your input and create the according label in *each* iteration.

Comment: @hbaderts what do you mean? do you mean the expected output to the inputs?

Comment: You should not 1) go through all bananas, 2) go through all apples, 3) go through all carrots. If you have an input array, shuffle the rows, or as you generate your data on-the-fly, randomly create bananas/apples/carrots in each iteration.

Comment: @hbaderts do you mean like that? it's the **train** function now https://hastebin.com/simeravexi.cpp

Comment: Yes exactly, I guess that should improve the learning.

Comment: @hbaderts I think it did, thank you, though the problem still stays that it picks the last learned object :D

Comment: @hbaderts I can say that because I get the output of each iteration of the **train** function. And when I try to recognize the input it picks the last learned object

Comment: @EthanGills what is more common is that every iteration, you shuffle the training array with a shuffle function, and then you backpropagate them one by one.

Comment: @ThomasW oh, I see D: thank you, but would it make a difference in this particular case?

Comment: @ThomasW looking forward to it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EthanGills sorry it was right after all. But something else is wrong (I think): you aren't normalizing your input values. You are inputting values like `10` and `20`, but your values should be inside of the `0` and `1` range. So the inputs should look like this `10 -> 10/30 = 0.33`. So after you have selected an input, you should normalize it to a number between `0` and `1` first.

Comment: @ThomasW omg, it worked, finally, thank you a lot!!!! thank you dude ;_____________;

Comment: @EthanGills no problem, i'll write it down as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you select a random number between 0-30 and then determine an output for it, however you are forgetting to normalize the input. Neural networks function best if the input is within the range of `0-1` (depends on which activation function you use).

So what is left for you to do is to do *normalize* this input. That means, converting the inputs equally to a number between `0` and `1`.

Your input is a numerical value, so all you have to do is choose a maximum value with which you divide all the values. In your case, this could be `30`, as there is no input higher than `30`. So each number gets converted as follows:

```
10 -> 10 / 30 -> 0.33
15 -> 15 / 30 -> 0.50
etc.
```

Read more about normalization [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic/wiki/Normalization-101).